# When to perform Asr prayer

Tags: salat

In Bangladesh generally hanafi madhab is followed.So call for Asr prayer is given which it is twice length shadow plus shadow at its zawal time.I read in a residential institution.Suppose time for Asr starting time is 3.10pm according to Shafii and 3.55pm according to Hanafi madhhab.The time for sunset is 5.35pm.But I have no scope to perform salat from 3.25pm to 4.40 pm.So which thing is best for me?Is it to perform salat before the  call for Asr prayer at 4.00 pm as in Islam it is told not to delay in Islam or it is better to perform salat after 4.40pm as Adhan(call for prayer) is needed for prayer.Please give proof to your answer basing on hadith.

Comment: IMO this question should be closed it is not only a duplicate of an existing and answered question, it was also asked by the OP before as a partial question beside the fact that this is a specific matter with no general benfit for others!

Comment: You can perform any fard prayer between the adhan time of the actual prayer until the adhan time of the following, but it is recommended to perform it as early as possible. So if you stick on hanafi madhab do it at 4:40 else be aware that calculation methods are not that exact.

Comment: How can it be duplicate one?I have given a condition that call for adhan I given at 4.00.So if I perform my prayer before 3.25 I am missing Sunnat e Muakkadah according to most of the hanafi scholars and wajib according to some of the hanafi scholars(source:Fatwa e Alamgiri).Again if I perform my salat after adhan I have to become late in performing prayer.I am asking which is the better choice here.

Comment: The answer of the duplicate question answers your question. The details you are asking about are not of general benefit as even at 4:40 you still can pray the sunna al muakada as it is simply a sunnah qabliya (sunnah which needs to be performed before fard) as you have enough time until maghrib adhan.

Comment: You haven't understood my question.I am asking which is better.If I perform my Salat at 4.40 pm then it becomes too late .Again I perform my Salat at 3.20pm according to Shafi madhab it becomes early but then Salat is performed before adhan.

Comment: 4:40 isn't too late you still have about one hour till maghrib!

Answer (score 0):

i think you have these options to select from:

- pray after 4.40 because there is a hadith:
  https://sunnah.com/bukhari/9/55

> Narrated Abu Huraira: Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "Whoever could get
>   one rak'a (of the Fajr prayer) before sunrise, he has got the
>   (morning) prayer and whoever could get one rak'a of the 'Asr prayer
>   before sunset, he has got the ('Asr) prayer."

- pray before 3.25 but after 3.10, because, as i know, 1 length shadow is also accepted in hanafi mazhab: proof:
  http://islamqa.org/hanafi/qibla-hanafi/34498

> However, the one shadow-length opinion, which is the position of Abu
>   Hanifa’s main students, Abu Yusuf and Muhammad ibn al-Hasan, was also
>   chosen by major Hanafi imams, as mentioned by al-Haskafi in Durr
>   al-Mukhtar and by al-Shurunbulali in Maraqi al-Falah.

moreover, i think, one length version, which is accepted by majority of hanafi scholars, seems is error, because i have not seen any hadith that says that. >after half an hour: [i have found now](https://sunnah.com/malik/1/9) though it does not clearly say that 2 shadows is asr time's start. < for example, see this site: http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=92052 : and the hadith which they show as evidence for that position in fact says its time is from 1 length to 2 lengths!

- pray before 3.10, from zuhr time, which is nearly in 12:10, because it is not said in the hadithes "plus shadow at its zawal time". [i have asked about this here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17723/prove-zenith-shadow-addition-to-shadow-of-1-height-of-object-to-get-asr-prayer). one length means 45 degrees of sun above 0 degree horizon line, and as i see in [stellarium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellarium_(software)), even at zenith sun is under or nearly at 45 degrees.