# What to do when Isha times on mosque calendar is wrong?

Tags: salat, prayer-timings

2 days ago, I was going to pray Isha. The mosque timetable said Isha starts at 10:38. However, Isha starts when twilight finishes.

> رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم عَنْ وَقْتِ الصَّلَوَاتِ فَقَالَ ‏ "‏ وَقْتُ صَلاَةِ الْفَجْرِ مَا لَمْ يَطْلُعْ قَرْنُ الشَّمْسِ الأَوَّلُ وَوَقْتُ صَلاَةِ الظُّهْرِ إِذَا زَالَتِ الشَّمْسُ عَنْ بَطْنِ السَّمَاءِ مَا لَمْ يَحْضُرِ الْعَصْرُ وَوَقْتُ صَلاَةِ الْعَصْرِ مَا لَمْ تَصْفَرَّ الشَّمْسُ وَيَسْقُطْ قَرْنُهَا الأَوَّلُ وَوَقْتُ صَلاَةِ الْمَغْرِبِ إِذَا غَابَتِ الشَّمْسُ مَا لَمْ يَسْقُطِ الشَّفَقُ وَوَقْتُ صَلاَةِ الْعِشَاءِ إِلَى نِصْفِ اللَّيْلِ ‏"‏ ‏.‏
>
> [٦١٢ صحيح مسلم](https://sunnah.com/muslim/5/223)

When I looked at the sky, the twilight did not disappear and I don't think it ever disappeared.

**Question:** When should I have done salah as I could not combine it with Maghrib as I already prayed Maghrib?

Comment: Maybe These Posts are relevant https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17723/why-sunni-scholars-say-that-shadow-for-asr-time-should-be-measured-with-addition/40841#40841 and https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/32643/figuring-out-right-calculation-method-of-prayer-time/32744#32744